# How to override applied CSS rules in media queries?

Tags: css

I use jQuery to animate my page - a function called [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).  I can view this in the debugger and see the styles applied to my `<nav>` element.

The problem I'm facing, is that after I call slideToggle ( a second time ) it sets display:none to `<nav>` as it correctly should.

However, If I expand the screen again, the menu does not re-appear in its normal state as it should.

I set it in the media query but it is ignored.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){

/* This does nothing but I want it to turn the display on.
*/

nav {
  display: block;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question **can I override inline-css?** ... **Yes**, by using [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception).

**Your real question:**

By adding !important to your media query when the screen is big again. see following snippet (run in full screen and make screen smaller/bigger)

```js
(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(e){
    $('#test').slideToggle();
  });
})();
```

```css
  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
   ul {
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
   }
   li {

    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 50px;
   }
   #test {
    display: block !important;
   }
   button {

    display: none !important;
   }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   ul {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
   }
   li {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
   }
   #test {
    display: none;
   }
   button {
    display: block;
   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
 <ul>
  <li>This</li>
  <li>Is</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>menu</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<button >Toggle menu</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't overwrite, it is striked-through because `display:static` does not exist. It's not correct css

Comment: I think I understand your real question. Ill update another answer. Just make sure your mediaquery when the screen is big is set with `!important` see updated answer / snippet

Comment: Not in my example, so I think there are inconsistencies.

Comment: Sigh it is a *very* simple test case. But you made another typo.  Both your media queries say `max-width`, like I said, my snippet works.

Comment: Don't fiddle lol, just change the first `max-width` to `min-width`.

Comment: It works now, why did you change the media query by 1px though?

Comment: If the width is exactly 800, css will apply both media-queries at the same time. This meaning! important will override at exactly 800px being the highest order.

Answer (score 6):

Media queries are irrelevant here. They don't affect [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html) at all.

Inline rules always trump rule-set rules unless the rule-set rule is `!important` and the inline rule is not.

Comment: Use an important rule and make sure that slideToggle does not.

Comment: Also use valid CSS. `static` is not accepted as a value for `display`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the most specific CSS selector will be applied to an element. The [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) is defined as follows (highlight by me):

> 1. Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in question, for the target media type. Declarations apply if the
>      associated selector matches the element in question and the target
>      medium matches the media list on all @media rules containing the
>      declaration and on all links on the path through which the style sheet
>      was reached.
> 2. Sort according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:
>
>    - user agent declarations
>    - user normal declarations
>    - author normal declarations
>    - author important declarations
>    - user important declarations
> 3. Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector: **more specific selectors will override more general ones**.
>      Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are counted as normal elements and
>      classes, respectively.
> 4. Finally, sort by order specified: **if two declarations have the same weight**, origin and specificity, **the latter specified wins**.
>      Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any
>      declarations in the style sheet itself.

Furthermore, you can forcefully apply a style using the [`!important` keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules). You should not use the declaration, however, unless it is absolutely necessary after all other avenues have been exhausted. I recommend reading [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) if you want to learn more about the `!important` keyword, when to use it and why to avoid it.

Comment: To clarify, media queries do NOT add specificity, in case anyone was unsure how media queries rules vs ("regular) rules interacted. media queries do NOT add specificity, so order is the defining feature here. To override a specific media query rule, append a new css rule after the one you want to override. For example, if the last css rule does not have a media query attached, it will override all previously declared media queries (presuming the same selectors). They will follow all the rules exactly as this Answer provides.

Answer (score -1):

this will work 100%;

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px){

```
/* This does nothing but I want it to turn the display on.
*/

nav {
  display: static !important;
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class in the media query and call addClass in your function.

By the way
You set display: block; for nav when max-width: 1000px
It should be MIN-width if you want to display the nav when the screen widens.